# Is $k[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Is $k[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ a UFD?

I think it is not. Assuming that the elements $x,y,z$ are irreducible, the polynomial $f=xz$ can be written in two ways as a product of irreducible polynomials, namely $f=xz=y^2$.

How do I show $x,y,z$ are irreducible and that $y^2-xz$ is prime (i.e. that the $k[x,y,z]/(y^2-xz)$ is an integral domain)?

Comment: Your ring is graded, $x$ is homogeneous of degree one, so a decomposition of $x$ necessarily involves a degree zero (that is, an element of $k$) and a degree one element.